# Tomcat overrides application.properties file in eclipse

Tags: java, tomcat, apache-camel, classpath, application.properties

I'm trying to run my camel application on external tomcat. There are 2 *application.properties* files present in my project, one under src/main/resources and other under src/test/resources. When I create war file using maven install command, it uses the application.properties file from src/main/resources (which is needed) but when I start the application using tomcat in eclipse, it is using application.properties file from src/test/resources. I've also removed classpath entry of src/test/resources from eclipse but no luck. I'm not really sure how is it picking the application.properties file from src/test/resources.

When I delete the application.properties file present under src/test/resources then it works fine i.e. then it picks the application.properties file present under src/main/resources.

We are using:

- Oracle JDK 8
- Spring 4.3.11.RELEASE
- Tomcat 8.5
- Camel 2.20.2
- ActiveMQ 5.15.0
- Maven Build Tool

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recreated the same scenario. But In my case I am getting application.properties from main when I build the project from both eclipse and mvn from terminal. Check which file is getting included in target/calsses directory when you build from both places

Answer (score 0):

When Eclipse deploys a project to a server the important setting is the *"Deployment Assembly*", not the *"Java Build Path"*. If you remove the `src/test/resources` folder from the deployment assembly, the files it contains will not be copied.